# How to use capacitor camera preview in a Vue.js app?

Tags: vue.js, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have a Vue.js app and I want to use capacitor camera preview plugin.
But when I run the app on web I get this error on the console
Also it does not work in IOS as well.

Here is the documentation of the plugin
https://github.com/capacitor-community/camera-preview#readme

[image]

Here is my component

```
<template>
  <div>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import '@capacitor-community/camera-preview'
import { CameraPreview } from '@capacitor-community/camera-preview';

const cameraPreviewOptions = {
  position: 'rear',
  height: 1920,
  width: 1080
};

export default {
  created() {
    CameraPreview.start(cameraPreviewOptions);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? It sounds like you have to upgrade to the latest one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I fixed my problem. Turns out I need to add cameraPreview as an id to a div in my html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `id="cameraPreview"` and my problem is fixed

```js
<template>
  <div id="cameraPreview">
    
  </div>
</template>
```